# How to avoid checking all fields for nullable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a TypeScript interface defined as follows:

```
export interface SessionTime {
   id: number
   startTimeFriendly: string
   startTime: string
}
```

Is there a way I can make all of these fields null?

```
const sessionTime : SessionTime = {...}
```

That is, without having to update the existing type with "?".(see below):

```
export interface SessionTime {
   id?: number
   startTimeFriendly?: string
   startTime?: string
}
```

**Can I somehow declare something like** `const sessionTime : SessionTime? = {...}`  **and get the same thing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), whose [definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5afe42e14e61d7e4df5d75cc0022283711cb593a/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1473) is

```
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which makes each of the properties optional (note the `?` in the definition).  This works as you expect:

```
const sessionTime: Partial<SessionTime> = {} // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWAGciEIkAVBAWzwG8AoOZxAEwC44kBXagIzRMWRGJlhVaAMSgJgSVgBsAnpxEykAcyHMRYmBOCqY6rQF8GFhtnIi4RYqXIHOABT0JMCgDyESZSjTAAHxwALxwdKZwAPTRcBAA1phKDEA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

```
type SessionTimePartial = Partial<SessionTime>;
const sessionTime : SessionTimePartial = {...}
```